# Only show a portion of a number from a field

Tags: sql

I have an ID number that is like 12345_B24L_54321. The underscore is always present but the preceding and trailing numbers are always different. I need to display the characters between the underscores only.

```
SUBSTRING(itemID, 1, CHARINDEX('_', ItemID +  ) AS PartID
```

The result I get is everything past the _ is not displayed.
I need to see everything between the underscores.

Comment: "Questions should include ... a tag for the DBMS implementation"

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the characters between the two '_' then I would substring the ID twice; once for what is to the right of the first underscore, and then again for what is left of the second underscore.

In Oracle, it would be:

```
SUBSTR(
    SUBSTR(ItemID, INSTR(ItemID,'_')+1),
    1,
    INSTR(SUBSTR(ItemID, INSTR(ItemID,'_')+1),'_')-1
)
```

For the Syntax you provided above, I think It would be:

```
SUBSTRING(
    SUBSTRING(ItemID, CHARINDEX(ItemID,'_')+1),
    1,
    CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(ItemID, CHARINDEX(ItemID,'_')+1),'_')-1
)
```